# Can't seem to hide followed hyperlinks with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I ran into a peculiar behavior today that I need help with.  I have a range(A2:C3) that I'm using conditional formatting to hide based on a yes/no dropdown (A1). It basically sets font/border/and bg color to white. There's a cell with a hyperlink (A3) to clear the contents of the range (A2:C3) which should be included when the range formatting is changed.

It works well until you click the link, then it isn't included with the range for conditional formatting for some reason.  Any ideas on a solution to get followed hyperlinks to behave as new hyperlinks?  I'd like to keep everything within the conditional formatting scheme to save myself a heap of work but if VBA is needed that's fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the column, row or cells.

Format Cells

Uncheck normal font.

:)

This deselects auto formating for things like hyper links.

Comment: Sweet crap that worked like a charm, of course I lost the link formatting that gave it away but I can that manually!

Oddly, normal font was already unchecked but toggling it on/off seemed to work!